# Why is sync feature not working in my phone?

Tags: sync

[image]

No account is syncing in my android phone since 25 feb 2021.

Already tried

- Rebooting
- updating all apps
- resetting settings only(cannot reset storage)
- removing and re adding account.
- different internet connections.
- tried same google accounts on other android phones, they work  with sync fine.

[image: screenshot][image: ss2]

I can't erase whole data(even after backup), personal reasons.

Phone model : realme 5 pro

Android version : 10

Please help

Comment: You should edit your question and give a little more details like used device model, Android version. Have you tried different Internet connections?

Comment: Try signing out of your Google account and signing in //Also are the Gmail accounts to which Google accounts are associated with - are these Google accounts all added to the device?

Comment: I removed all my google accounts and added just one google account again. Then it synced.  Getting 'access to keep is unauthorised' though. I think it's a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all my google accounts and added just one google account again. Then it synced. Getting 'access to keep is unauthorised' though. Also 'authentication is required' error was showing in play store.

Then i followed
[www.nextpit.com/how-to-fix-google-play-authentication-is-required-error](http://www.nextpit.com/how-to-fix-google-play-authentication-is-required-error)

Go to Settings > Apps & notifications
Scroll down to Google Play Store, tap it, then tap Storage & cache and then Clear cache.
Do the same for Google Play Services

It worked for me.